# PayPal, notify_url has never been executed

Tags: php, api, paypal

I have a problem at the IPN : the URL entered in the hidden input **"notify_url"** is never taken in considiration!

When I confirm my payment, I am redirected to my page back (hidden field "return").

What's wrong ?

Thaks.

PS : For the test, I put a simple mail function in the file ipn.php (the URL entered in the hidden input **"notify_url"**)

Comment: and If you access it directly it send email?

Comment: I just tried and the email was sent !

Comment: Without much information as you can provide, your form and emailing php file for example, your question suits paypal bug tracker. Anyway, paypal is sometimes mad and it does not send notifications correctly but that's very rare.

Comment: I'm in localhost, did this make the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

The notify URL must be accessible from outside - i.e. localhost will not work. The return URL does work on your machine because your browser can access it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Swiss Master said, IPN also needs to 'On' or 'Off' on your account, but *not* 'Disabled'.
If IPN is switched 'On', you will need to enter a URL in your PayPal Profile for IPN data (though you can still override which URL is used by sending notify_url on a per-transaction basis).

If IPN is switched 'Off', you will not receive IPN for all activities, but only for those where you sent notify_url in the transaction request itself.

If IPN is set to 'Disabled', no IPN messages will be generated at all, regardless of what you sent.
IPN will be automatically set to 'Disabled' if PayPal encounters non-HTTP 200 response codes from your IPN handler.
(For example, a HTTP 404, timeouts to the script, SSL errors when accessing the script, HTTP 500 errors, etc..)